# Centre combined divs

Tags: css, html, center

EDIT: All sorted now. Thanks to everyone that helped! :)

I am having trouble centering an element of my website. It is 3 divs mixed together to form a hexagon.

I cannot center it.

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="centerhex">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="hexa">
            <div class="hexcontainer">
              <div class="vertical-align">
                <span class="hextext">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.centerhex {
left: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
width:210px;
height:300px;
}

.hexa {
width: 100%;
min-width: 200px;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 57.7%;
margin-top: 65px;
background-color: #4a4a4a;
/*position: absolute;*/
color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
border-radius: 4%/20%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.hexa::before,
.hexa::after {
content:"";
display: block;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
padding: inherit;
background: inherit;
z-index: 0;
position: absolute;
border-radius: inherit;
-moz-transform:rotate(60deg);  
-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);  
-o-transform:rotate(60deg);  
-ms-transform:rotate(60deg);
}

.hexa::after {
-moz-transform:rotate(-60deg);  
-webkit-transform:rotate(-60deg);  
-o-transform:rotate(-60deg);  
-ms-transform:rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexcontainer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}


.vertical-align {
display: table;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Also, I need help so the bottom of the shape isn't cut off.
URL: http://jackmarshallphotography.co.uk/V1/donate.html

Comment: For the problem "shape cut off", can you tell us which tag triggers the mouseover effect?

Comment: Set `div.servicebox` to a width of 914px. That is the width of your wrapper minus the 35px padding on the left and right of `div.box-container` This will center the hexagon :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to change in your css, I worked directly on your website with the chrome developer tool, please find below the css to center the "tag" :

```
.servicebox {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -77px;
width: 100%;
}

.servicebox ul {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.servicebox ul li {
margin-left: 12px;
}

.centerhex {
margin: auto;
width: 210px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

For the second issue :

you need to edit the file hexagon.css and change the margin-top property find the right value: -65px or more (line 47)

Yoann

Comment: I am on your website on chrome and the tag is centered, what browser are you using?

Comment: It's centered because part of what Sam suggested is being used.

Comment: Ok, Sorry, just saw your comment, do you want have a look to the cut off issue?

Comment: Yes please. Also, the hexagon doesn't look exactly centered. I am really confused here. To be quite honest I don't really know why what  you and Sam suggested works together. I have used Sams method before however it didn't work on this. That's the problem when you use purchased themes. You don't know what techniques have been used and how it has been coded. I think that something is trying to override what is currently being used.

Comment: Ok, first for the cutt off issue, you need to edit the file hexagon.css and change the margin-top property find the right value (line 47)

Comment: This just changes how far it moves on hover.
What I would like is that the container that holds the hexagon gets extended downwards so the whole hexagon is present.
I could fix it by adding <br> tags underneath the hexagon div, but is there a simpler way with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can help you with a simple example.

Have a fiddle - [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9qN8C/)!

**Edit!** - Here is another fiddle without absolute positioning... seems like this can be achieved without it - [fiddle link - no absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/9qN8C/1/)

Absolute positioning example:

HTML

```
<div id="parentOfCentered">
    <div id="perfectlyCentered"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parentOfCentered {
    position: relative; /*  Absolutely positioned children will be positioned in relation to the parent div */
    background: #CCC;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
#perfectlyCentered {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px; 
   /*  
       - negative top margin of half the height
       - negative left margin of half the width
   */
}
```

Comment: It seems that Yoann's suggestion doesn't work on it's own.
However it does work with parts of the "perfectlyCentered" div from your suggestion.

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Cool, well depending on where you want it vertically put a negative top margin in the same property as the negative left margin :)

Comment: That's not what I mean. I like it where it currently is, but I want to extend the container div downwards.

Comment: Possibly you could add a `min-height` on `section.box-container`. Then that would keep the hexagon at the bottom when the text extends past that min-height.

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle link in my edit, couldn't the same thing be achieved without absolute positioning? Would be easier... Bit late now  however :)